# How to display final point value in charts.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using Charts.js library to display a line graph from data which is constantly updated. Is there a way to display only the final point value at all times? I want it to do this to monitor the added values at all times.

[image]

javascript code:

```
var config2 = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
  labels: 0,
  datasets: [{ 
    label: "No selection",
    lineTension: 0,
    borderColor: "rgba(222, 44, 31)",
    pointBackgroundColor: "#fff675",
    fill: false,

    data: 0,
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: false,
      text: 'Chart.js Time Point Data'
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Date'
        },
        ticks: {
          major: {
            enabled: true
          },
          fontStyle: function(context) {
            return context.tick && context.tick.major ? 'bold' : undefined;
          },
          fontColor: function(context) {
            return context.tick && context.tick.major ? '#FF0000' : undefined;
          }
        }
      },
      y: {
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'value'
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time, a new value is available, you can simply remove outdated `labels` and `dataset.data` values once a certain limit is reached. This can be done using [`Array.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift), which removes the first element from an `array`. Once these array are updated, you need to invoke `chart.update()`.

```
var maxValues = 4;
setInterval(() => {
  chart.data.labels.push(new Date());
  chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1));
  if (chart.data.labels.length > maxValues) {
    chart.data.labels.shift();
    chart.data.datasets[0].data.shift();
  }
  chart.update();
}, 1000);
```

For displaying the value on the last added data point, you can use the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). It offers different hooks that may be used for executing custom code. In below runnable code snippet, I use the `afterDraw` hook to draw text directly on the `canvas`.

```js
var chart = new Chart('chart', {
  type: "line",
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      var iLastValue = chart.data.labels.length - 1;
      var lastValue = chart.data.datasets[0].data[iLastValue];
      var x = xAxis.getPixelForValue(chart.data.labels[iLastValue]);
      var y = yAxis.getPixelForValue(lastValue);
      ctx.save();
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.font = '14px Arial';
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      ctx.fillText('Value: ' + lastValue, x, y - 15);
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Data",
      data: [],
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0,
      backgroundColor: "white",
      borderColor: "red",
    }]
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        right: 50
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        ticks: {
          source: 'auto'
        },
        time: {
          unit: 'second',
          displayFormats: {
            second: 'mm:ss'
          },
          tooltipFormat: 'mm:ss'
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 20,
          stepSize: 5
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});

var maxValues = 4;
setInterval(() => {
  chart.data.labels.push(new Date());
  chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1));
  if (chart.data.labels.length > maxValues) {
    chart.data.labels.shift();
    chart.data.datasets[0].data.shift();
  }
  chart.update();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yes I could def do this, but what I'm trying to present in my chart is data behaviour during an entire day, which then resets once the next day arrives. 

Which is why I want the last point in the chart to always display its value without the need to hover the mouse to it, since the graph can get pretty large by the time the day is about to end.

Comment: @Ruben Jose Diaz: I updated my answer according to your comment. I hope this reflects what you're looking for.